# How to select an item in LongListSelector using the MVVM-pattern?

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, mvvm, longlistselector

I'm building application using the MVVM pattern. After clicking on one of the elements I want to see this element's details. I wrote this:

XAML

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,158"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button>
                <!-- Command="{Binding ShowDetailsAction}"-->
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable SelectedItem
{
    get { return _itemsControl; }
    set
    {
        if (_itemsControl == value)
            return;
        _itemsControl = value;

        // Test
        _mss.ErrorNotification("fd");
    }
}
```

I tried also using a command, which didn't work, too.

This was the command part:

```
public ICommand ShowDetailsCommand { get; private set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    _loadDataCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoadDataAction);
    SaveChangesCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveChangesAction);
    ShowDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowDetailsAction);
}

private void ShowDetailsAction(object p)
{
    _mss.ErrorNotification("bla bla");
}
```

**EDIT**

ViewModel

```
private IEnumerable _itemsControl;
public IEnumerable Data
{
  get
  {
    return _itemsControl;
  }
  set
  {
    _itemsControl = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
  }
}

protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Model

```
public string Text { get; set; }
public DateTimeOffset Data { get; set; }
```

**EDIT2**

```
private MobileServiceCollection<ModelAzure, ModelAzure> _items;
        private readonly IMobileServiceTable<ModelAzure> _todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<ModelAzure>();


private async void RefreshTodoItems()
{
   try
    {
        _items = await _todoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
    }
   catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
     {
          _mss.ErrorNotification(e.ToString());
     }
   Data = _items;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to define explicitly your binding to SelectedItem in TwoWay mode? (try SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}")

Comment: I added Mode=TwoWay but do not work.

Comment: Could you please provide more code of your viewmodel? It could be useful to take a look at your Data property and its content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Data` property looks like

```
private MobileServiceCollection<ModelAzure, ModelAzure> _itemsControl;
public MobileServiceCollection<ModelAzure, ModelAzure> Data
{
  get
  {
    return _itemsControl;
  }
  set
  {
    _itemsControl = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
  }
}
```

**Edited**

It seems the [SelectedItem property from LongListSelector cannot be bound in WP8](http://dotnet-redzone.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/windows-phone-8longlistselector.html).
What you can do is either :

- Use the derived and fixed custom LongListSelector provided in the link above instead of the default one, which looks like :

  ```
  public class LongListSelector : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector
  {
      public LongListSelector()
      {
          SelectionChanged += LongListSelector_SelectionChanged;
      }

      void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          SelectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(
              "SelectedItem",
              typeof(object),
              typeof(LongListSelector),
              new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged)
          );

      private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          var selector = (LongListSelector)d;
          selector.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
      }

      public new object SelectedItem
      {
          get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
          set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
      }
  }
  ```
- Register the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event from LongListSelector and call your ViewModel by yourself inside the associated handler/callback :

in your view :

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="YourLongListSelectorName"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,158"
                        SelectionChanged="OnSelectedItemChanged">
```

in your code behind :

```
private void OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((YourViewModel)this.DataContext).NewSelectedItemMethodOrWhateverYouWant((ModelAzure)this.YourLongListSelectorName.SelectedItem);
    //or
    ((YourViewModel)this.DataContext).SelectedItem = (ModelAzure)this.YourLongListSelectorName.SelectedItem;
}
```

Finally your `Button` command wasn't properly working, because when you use a `DataTemplate`, the ambiant DataContext is the item itself. Which means that it was looking for your `Command` into your `Model` instance, not into your `ViewModel` instance.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not sure.. but _itemsControl cannot be type of IEnumerable and Model in this same time.

Comment: SelectionChanged="OnSelectedItemChanged" <-- Incorrect method signature. 
In behind code accept only signature: (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)

Comment: I created method:   internal void Selected(object p)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(p);
        }
and output is just: PanoramaITWEM.Model.ModelAzure

Comment: Is internal void Selected(object p) { Debug.WriteLine(p); } a ViewModel Method? If it does, it seems quite normal to me. You are assigning Data = _items; (code taken from EDIT2), and _items is of type MobileServiceCollection<ModelAzure, ModelAzure>. So basically _items is a collection of ModelAzure instances, and selecting an item of it, gives you a ModelAzure instance. Just cast p into ModelAzure to access its properties. Code updated

Comment: Maybe it's stupid question, maybe I am tired or don't know how to do that.. but object is  Model type. I Have no idea how can I get for example Text value.

Comment: If ModelAzure if your Model type, then you have to cast your object into ModelAzure. In the code i provided and into OnSelectedItemChanged, i have casted SelectedItem into ModelAzure (like this (ModelAzure)this.YourLongListSelectorName.SelectedItem). So now, you just have to change "internal void Selected(object p) { Debug.WriteLine(p); }" into "internal void Selected(ModelAzure p) { Debug.WriteLine(p.Text); }"

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel, you have:

```
public IEnumerable SelectedItem
{
get { return _itemsControl; }
set
{
    if (_itemsControl == value)
        return;
    _itemsControl = value;

    // Test
    _mss.ErrorNotification("fd");
}
```

}

Why is your SelectItem an IEnumerable?  Should it not be of type "Model"?  Your list is bound to "Data" which should be ObservableList, not IEnumerable. It will provide it's own change notification, so you don't need to.

The list will set the SelectedItem when it gets selected, but if the type is wrong, it won't get set.

Greg

Comment: Because I'm reading data from Azure. Loading  data to IEnumerable was easier than to Observable...  I added more code to my post